# Run okular 1.13 on Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: okular

I would very much like to run Okular 1.3 on my Kubuntu 16.04 installation, rather than the old version that comes with 16.04. However, I have not been able to find any backports, and only version 1.0 available as a snap.

Is there any PPA somewhere, or some other way of finding snaps, that might make it possible to run Okular 1.3 under Kubuntu 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Flatpak (see [KDE Guidelines](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Flatpak), you will get Okular 1.4.70 from KDE Platform 18.04, which [is the latest](https://github.com/KDE/okular/blob/c325b342f316109c0dd3ba9d50b8413258a9c5b6/CMakeLists.txt)).

1. Install it

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install flatpak
   ```
2. Add KDE repo

   ```
   flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub \
   https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
   flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists kdeapps --from \
   https://distribute.kde.org/kdeapps.flatpakrepo
   ```
3. Install Okular

   ```
   flatpak install kdeapps org.kde.okular
   ```
4. Run Okular

   ```
   flatpak run org.kde.okular
   ```